# Is the phrase "use someone" sometimes good and sometimes bad?

Tags: word-choice, meaning-in-context

I don't really know if this is the right place to ask this, but I am sure someone will know. When you say "someone used you", isn't that bad? But, when you say "I could use someone", isn't that good? What makes the difference? Thanks!

Comment: Hello, Aidan, and welcome to EL&U. Your question is a little broad, and depends on context, as you seem to be aware of. There are all kinds of possibilities here...could you please narrow it down?

Answer (score 3):

The difference is in the context. Using can refer to *exploiting* for one's own advantage, as in "someone used you for your money." The second meaning you refer to is *benefiting* from, as in "I could use someone to talk to."

Comment: Hello Bento, welcome to EL&U. Your answer is succinct and nicely argued and you just beat me to it! I've just given you your first upvote.